# Test for morse coding which accepts ( \n)

Tags: python, unit-testing

i want to do this test:

```
  def test_morse_word_new_line_2(self):
        morse = ".... ---\n.--. "
        inputed_data = "ho\np"
        self.assertEqual(morse, self.temp.coding(inputed_data)
```

But it does raise an exception, because it is not a part of my `morse translation dictionary`
I tried adding `\n` to this dictionary, but it didnt work well.
Can someone tell me how to change this code, so it would accept \n?

```
class Morse:
    def __init__(self):
        self.MORSE_CODE = {' ': '   ', 'A': '.-', 'B': '-...',
                           'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.',
                           'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
                           'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-',
                           'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
                           'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-',
                           'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-',
                           'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--',
                           'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',
                           '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--',
                           '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....',
                           '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
                           '0': '-----', ', ': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-',
                           '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.', '-': '-....-',
                           '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', "&": ".-...",
                           "'": ".----.", "@": ".--.-.", ":": "---...",
                           ",": "--..--", "=": "-...-", "!": "-.-.--",
                           "+": ".-.-.", '"': ".-..-.", 'Ą': ".-.-",
                           "Ć": "-.-..", "Ę": "..-..", "Ł": ".-..-",
                           "Ń": "--.--", "Ó": "---.", "Ś": "...-...",
                           }
        self.morse_code_letters = ['', '.-', '-...', '-.-.', '-..', '.', '..-.', '--.', '....', '..', '.---', '-.-',
                                   '.-..', '--', '-.', '---', '.--.', '--.-', '.-.', '...', '-', '..-', '...-', '.--',
                                   '-..-', '-.--', '--..', '-----', '.----', '..---', '...--', '....-', '.....',
                                   '-....',
                                   '--...', '---..', '----.', '--..--', '.-.-.-', '..--..', '-.-.-.', '---...', '-..-.',
                                   ".--.-.", "---...", "--..--", "-...-", "-.-.--", ".-.-.", ".-..-.",
                                   '..--.-', '-.-.--', '-....-', '.-.-.', '-.--.', '-.--.-', '-...-', '.--.-.',
                                   '--..--', '.-.-.-', '..--..', '-..-.', '-....-', '-.--.', '-.--.-', ".-...",
                                   ".----.", ]

    def coding(self, message):
        translation = ''

        for letter in message:
            if letter.upper() in self.MORSE_CODE.keys():
                if letter.upper() != ' ':
                    translation += self.MORSE_CODE[letter.upper()] + ' '
                else:
                    translation += '    '
            else:
                raise Exception
        return translation
```

Comment: You can simply remove the raise clause and replace by some sentinel when character is missing. What is your expected output for missing character?

Comment: By the way the space detection is redundant because it is already implemented in your dictionary. Another solution is to add new line in dictionary as well. It will definitely make this implementation simpler.

Comment: Just add `"\n": "\n"` to your dictionary, since that's what your unit test case seems to expect. Or replace the `raise Exception` by `translation += letter`. The correct answer depends on you: what do you want your function to do with other characters? First answer that question, then implementation should become simple.